# Group by and create new column in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I have a large dataset and I would like to create a new column that shows the State base off the many zip codes from the Postal code column.

```
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack', 'Petter'], 'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18, 52], 'Postal Code': [12345, 56789,12345, 96385, 56789]}
```

this is what I tried:

```
def city (row):
   if row['Postal Code'] == 12345 | 96385:
      return 'Utah'
k = data.apply (lambda row: city(row), axis=1)
```

I get the error "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'apply'"

expected result:

```
name | age | postal code | State|
--------------------------------
Tom  | 20  |    12345    | Utah |
```

I think there are better ways to do this, do you any any better approach?
Thank you!

Comment: it is telling you that `data` is a dict, you  need to `import pandas as pd` and then convert it to a df by `data = pd.DataFrame(data)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```py
# create a dictionary that maps postcode to state
d = {
    12345: 'Utah',
    96385: 'Utah',
}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['State'] = df['Postal Code'].map(d)
# or
df = (pd.DataFrame(data)
      .pipe(lambda df: df.assign(State=df['Postal Code'].map(d))))
# or
df = (pd.DataFrame(data)
      .eval('State = `Postal Code`.map(@d)'))
```

```
print(df)

     Name  Age  Postal Code State
0     Tom   20        12345  Utah
1    nick   21        56789   NaN
2   krish   19        12345  Utah
3    jack   18        96385  Utah
4  Petter   52        56789   NaN
```